# No longer have to enter a password to SSH into another server?

Tags: linux, networking, unix, permissions, authentication

For some reason, I have a server that if ssh into another server...you don't need to enter the  password.

How is this done? Can someone give me step by step instructions please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out this [article](http://linuxproblem.org/art_9.html). Essentially, I believe you're looking to generate and share keys between the local and remote machines in each ~/.ssh folder. The article outlines it better than I could. (And if that fails you, it's an easily Google-able subject).

Answer (score 2):

ssh keys + an ssh-agent, you may also want to look into keychain. Read the following set of gentoo articles by Daniel Robbins for a good overview on [openssh key management](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/articles/openssh-key-management-p1.xml).

Answer (score 2):

Most likely host-based authentication is enabled.

Look for the section on host-based authentication in the ssh manpage, and look for RhostsRSAAuthentication or HostbasedAuthentication in /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Comment: +1 In absence of any further details from OP and the OP having not taken any extra steps to establish an identity key pair this is the best possible reason for this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

SSH Keys.  Try `man ssh-keygen`.  Basically the machine you SSH into has a key (in ~/.ssh) that the machine to automatically ssh into generated.